# What is an example of an infinite group such that every nontrivial subgroup thereof is infinite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> What is an example of an infinite group such that every nontrivial subgroup thereof is infinite?

Comment: Would the additive group of integers not count?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia I see nothing in the OP that would suggest it doesn't.  A more interesting (but still easy to find) example might be the "dual": what's an example of an infinite group for which every non-trivial quotient is infinite?  $\mathbb Z$ doesn't work anymore, but infinite simple groups would fit the bill, though perhaps it would be more interesting if the group had "lots" of normal subgroups in some sense.

Comment: @zibadawa timmy, $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian and thus lots of normal subgroups and all non-trivial  quotients are infinite.

Answer (score 4):

The integers (under addition), $\Bbb Z$, does the trick. More generally all (nontrivial) [free groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) have this property, and in fact the [Nielsen-Schreier Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem) gives that every subgroup of a free group is itself free.